# java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException is coming while accessing JAVA web service

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed a JAVA web service and deployed it on my local apache server, it is running on port 7090, but while accessing my web service end point

http://localhost:7090/information_service/getAllStudents/

either through POSTMAN or in terminal through CURL command or using JAVA web client it is always giving 500 internal server error with response as follows:

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"> 
<ns1:faultstringxmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
   java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
```

I have tested network reachability for port 7090 of my machine with telnet, it is working properly. So I think it is not a connectivity issue. I am stuck, getting no clue why the issue is coming and how to solve it.

Comment: You can check the running server with "netstat -an". Find a TCP service with port 7090 and check if it's bound to localhost/IP: 127.0.0.1 or ::1 (IPv6). Check with "nslookup localhost" if an address is returned. And maybe "ping localhost".

Comment: I have checked with netstat -an|grep '7090', it returned tcp46 0 0 .7090 *. LISTEN

Comment: You server does not seems to be bound to localhost. Can you try to use the IP address or host name to connect?